# Differential equation with logarithm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'+\ln y+1=0$

$y' +ln(y) +1 = 0$

$y' = -ln(y) - 1$

$dy = [ -ln(y) - 1 ] dx$

$-\frac{dy}{(ln(y)+1)} = dx$

But I am stuck here..

Comment: The solution is not an elementary function.

Comment: @science Yes you are right. I meant it cannot. It is an incomplete Gamma function though.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y = e^{-1}z$

Use the [li function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

Comment: Well the hint in the problem is telling me to express the solutions as a combination of elementary functions. It's a incomplete Gamma function

Comment: Sorry it cannot be expressed as elementary functions. It is an incomplete Gamma function

Comment: @kryomaxim Can you develop the li idea ?